# Inputting multiple variable types into an ArrayList

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

Trying to make a program that schedules talks. I need to be able to input the title of the talk, the starting time, and the duration it lasts into a single array. Here's a snippet of my Application class, and my messy Event class.

```
ArrayList<Object> events = new ArrayList <Object>();


                        String title;
                        int hour, minute;
                        double duration;

                            System.out.println("Enter the title of the talk : ");
                            title = scnr.next();
                            System.out.println("Enter the start time");
                            System.out.println("Hour (0-23): ");
                            hour = scnr.nextInt();
                            System.out.println("Minute (0-23): ");
                            minute = scnr.nextInt();
                            System.out.println("Enter talk 's duration ( in minutes ) : ");
                            duration = scnr.nextDouble();
                            events.add(title);
                            events.add(hour);
                            events.add(minute);
                            events.add(duration);

                        }
public class Event {

private String title = "";
private double duration = 0.0, lectureTime = 60.0;
private int minute;

public Event(int hour, int minute) {
    this.minute = hour * 60 + minute;
}

public int getHour() {  
    return minute/60;
}
public int getMinute() {    
    return minute%60;

}
// Setter for hour
public void setHour(int hour) { 
    this.minute = getMinute() + hour*60;
}
// Setter for minute
public void setMinute(int minute) { 
    this.minute = getHour()*60 + minute;
}

public String toString()
{
    int h = (getHour()==0 || getHour()==12) ? getHour() : getHour()%12;
    String period = (getHour()<12)? "AM" : "PM";
    return String.format("Talk: %s (%02d:%02d %s to %02d:%02d %s )", getTitle(), h, getMinute(), period, getDuration(), period);
}   

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}
public double getDuration() {
    return duration;
}
public double getLectureTime() {
    return lectureTime;
}
public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}
public void setDuration(double duration) {
    this.duration = getMinute() + getMinute() + duration;
}
public void setLectureTime(double lectureTime) {
    this.lectureTime = lectureTime;
}
```

}

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: Shouldn't that be `ArrayList<Event>`?  You have a class to hold each event's data, why aren't you instantiating an `Event` and adding _that_ to the list? Why do you think you need to add the individual bits of information to the list?

Comment: what is the problem you are facing?

Answer (score 0):

You did it terribly wrong. Instead you can create ArrayList of `Event` class and add events object into the list. Like below :

```
ArrayList<Event> events = new ArrayList <Event>();
```

And then create event object based on input and add object into the list.

```
events.add(eventObj);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use "ArrayList" to hold your objects. Create Event object in your method, and these Event objects to your arraylist.